# How to compress multiple images and upload in FTP server from iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, compression, ftp-server

I am developing iPhone app for take photo and upload the photo in FTP server. From the app i want to `compress nearly 25 photos` taken by the user and `upload the compressed photos in FTP server`. Can anyone please guide me to `compress the images(Like ZIP)` and upload the compressed photos on FTP server. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gopinath can you guide me how to upload camera captured image to ftp server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitly try out this library -> http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/ . I've had good results zipping up to 3 images. Guess 25 will work as well

EDIT:

---

Here's a post of mine which has some sample code wich you can use :)

[How can I convert my Zip-file to NSData to email my Zip file as an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809359/how-can-i-convert-my-zip-file-to-nsdata-to-email-my-zip-file-as-an-attachment)

Comment: +1 that's the way you'd like to do. If you wanna go more deep level memory zipping you might use the c interface to libz and memory compress your NSData then sending it to you server. But first way is much more easy.